# JFrame freezes when button is pressed and operations from the other Class are ran

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to get a robot to follow around an object, it uses two sensors to decide on where to move.

I'm using a UI which include 'Start', 'Stop' and 'Quit' buttons. When the user hits 'Start', they will then have to tap the robot once to start the program. Another way to abort the program should be by tapping on the robot twice, this is in the followObject class, but I don't believe it is functional yet. Also, the movements that are made in the followObject class are to be appended onto the JFrame box. For example if the object is to the robot's right, I want 'Object detected to the right' to come up on the JFrame box.

However, when I click 'Start', the JFrame freezes - despite the successful calling and execution of the method resulting from the action of clicking it.

But I want users to still be able to stop or quit the program from this menu while the 'Finch' method plays out, how do I avoid this issue? I don't want to quit from Eclipse to stop or quit my program, obviously.

At a guess, I'd say its because the code in `Finch` doesn't give the UI a chance to update the JFrame, but I don't know how to work around this as I'm a beginner.

Here are my classes:

UI class optionFiveUI

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;

public class optionFiveUI  {

    public static optionFiveUI UI = new optionFiveUI(); 

    public static JButton start;
    public static JTextArea box;
    public static JButton stop;
    public static JButton exit;
    public static JFrame window;

    //Method for setting the UI

    static void GUI()
    {
        final JFrame window = new JFrame("Finch Activate, Option 5 : Follow an Object") ;
        //  Method of closing window
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //  Adding a layout
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //  Adding components and adding ActionListeners to buttons
        start = new JButton("Start");
        window.add(start);
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d)
            {
                box.append("You have started the program, place an object infront of the finch robot and tap\n");
                followObject.myf.sleep(5000);
                followObject.Finch();       
            }
        });
        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        window.add(stop);
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                box.append("You have stopped the program\n");   
                followObject.myf.stopWheels();
                followObject.myf.setLED(0, 0, 0);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window,"The program has been stopped. Please wait two seconds before pressing start to run the program again");
                followObject.myf.sleep(2000);
                window.repaint();
            }
        });
        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        window.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) 
            {
                followObject.myf.quit();
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        });                     
        box = new JTextArea(30,60);
        JScrollPane feedscroll = new JScrollPane(box);
        window.add(feedscroll);
        // Arrange components in window
        window.pack();
        // Making the window visible when called
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setEnabled(true);


    }
}
```

Follow class followObject:

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
import javax.swing.*;

public class followObject {

    static int Buzz = 500;
    static int BuzzDuration = 10;

    static int R = 255;
    static int G = 255;

    static int leftVelocity = 100;
    static int rightVelocity = 100;

    static int leftTurnV = -50;
    static int rightTurnV = -50;
    static int x = 0;

    protected static Finch myf = new Finch();

    private static int TapCount = 0;



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //refers to first method to start program
        optionFiveUI.GUI();
    }
    public static void Finch()
    {
        while (!myf.isBeakDown())
        {   
            if(myf.isTapped()&& x==0)
                {
                    if(myf.isObstacleLeftSide()&&myf.isObstacleRightSide())
                    {
                        x = 1;
                        myf.setLED(R,0,0);
                        myf.stopWheels();       
                    }
                }

                while(x==1)
                {   
                    // Calling Movement method  for Finch movements
                    Movement();
                    // Inside while RunAgain loop , there is the function called TapCount which counts number of taps
                    if (myf.isTapped()==true)
                    {
                        TapCount++;
                        optionFiveUI.box.append("You have tapped the Finch. When TapCount = 3 , the program will terminate (only if object is not moving)\n");
                        optionFiveUI.box.append("Number of Taps:" + TapCount + "\n");
                        if (TapCount==3 && myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==false)
                        {
                            myf.stopWheels();
                            myf.setLED(0, 0, 0);    
                            TapCount = 1;

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(optionFiveUI.window,"Please click OK and wait for 3 seconds. Make sure the object is not moving in order for program to terminate when you have tapped it twice");
                            myf.sleep(3000);
                        }
                        if (TapCount==3 && myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
                        {
                            myf.quit();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // Method for Finch movement

    private static void Movement()
    {
        if (myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==false)
        {
            // send message to the feedback box ("Following ahead");
            while(myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==false)
            {
                optionFiveUI.box.append("following ahead\n");
                StraightMovement();             
            }
        }
        if (myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==false)
        {
            while(myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==false)
            {
                optionFiveUI.box.append("Object detected to the left\n");  
                LeftMovement();             
            }
        }
        if (myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
        {
            while(myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==false && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
            {
                optionFiveUI.box.append("Object detected to the right\n");
                RightMovement();
            }
        }
        if (myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
        {
            while(myf.isObstacleLeftSide()==true && myf.isObstacleRightSide()==true)
            {
                StopMovement();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void StraightMovement()
    {
        myf.setLED(0, G, 0);
        myf.setWheelVelocities(leftVelocity, rightVelocity);
        myf.buzz(Buzz, BuzzDuration);
    }
    private static void LeftMovement()
    {
        myf.setLED(0, G, 0);
        myf.setWheelVelocities(leftTurnV, rightVelocity);
        myf.buzz(Buzz, BuzzDuration);
    }
    private static void RightMovement()
    {
        myf.setLED(0, G, 0);
        myf.setWheelVelocities(leftVelocity, rightTurnV);
        myf.buzz(Buzz, BuzzDuration);
    }
    private static void StopMovement()
    {
        myf.setLED(R, 0 , 0);
        myf.stopWheels();
    }   
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: So a lot of this stuff is a bit out of reach, could you try and be more specific with how to use the information you've given me to help in the context of my problem? If not then thankyou anyway.

Comment: Is it still possible to update the UI in the way I described with the updated edit to my question? When using the swingworker stuff, of course?